# Unable to read file at valid path from Scala IDE

Tags: scala, scala-ide, file-read

[image: Screenshot of code and error.]

I have tried all possible ways to rad file but all are giving same error.No   matter what way i try, code is unable to find the file. Please help.

Comment: Move your `word.txt` to `resources dir` , then do `val f = new File(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("word.txt").getPath)`

Comment: @Aman Kaushik: Try with `\\\` instead of `/` in the file path.

Comment: Please post code, not screen images. That makes it much easier to plug your code into a working IDE and test it.

Comment: Thanks Shankar.It worked.

Comment: Thanks Rohan and jwvh. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @Shankar Please post your comment as answer as it worked for OP

Comment: @AmanKaushik: If its working, please accept the answer. Thanks sag.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `\\` instead of `/` in the file path.